# ActiveRecord : which associations for places and routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, data-modeling

I would like to associates places within routes : one route has two places (start point and end point) + I need to store the distance btw those two points. I wonder if the data model is correct :
https://github.com/roms182/frais-kilometriques/blob/master/Annexes/shortmodel.png

And I am not sure how to settle associations in Rails.

```
class Place < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :routes
end

class Route < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :place
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route needs to be associate with two places -- the start and the end.

So one option would be:

```
class Place < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :routes_as_start, class_name: "Route", foreign_key: :start_place_id
  has_many :routes_as_end,   class_name: "Route", foreign_key: :end_place_id
end

class Route < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :start_place, class_name: "Place"
  belongs_to :end_place,   class_name: "Place"
end
```

However, if your routes do not have the formal concept of a start and end place -- i.e. they just join two places -- you may benefit from an intermediate model:

```
class Place < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :route_ends,
  has_many :routes, through: :ends
end

class RouteEnd
  belongs_to :place
  belongs_to :route
end

class Route < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :route_ends
  has_many :places, :through :route_end
end
```

In this context, `:has_many` should really be interpreted as `:has_two`.

This allows you to find all routes that terminate at a particular place more easily, without the concept that they are the "start" or "end".